# how to package .dll file

Tags: java, c, dll

I have some code files need to make a dll file. it is used by java loadlibrary(). how do I do?

g++ -m64 -c -O3 -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\include" -I "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\include\win32" chinesechess_database_Database.c myjni_Utilities.c

Comment: unpack it from your jar file, save it somewhere, then load it. Annoying, but, that's the way.

Comment: Are you asking how to build a DLL or how to package it in a Java application?